# How to change value in list for calendar?

Tags: python, string, list, function, calendar

The goal of my function is to book a slot in that calendar corresponding to the parameters day and time  - booking is done by changing the value in the calendar to “X” (to indicate that day/time is booked). Here is the code I have so far:

```
def find_index(val, seq):
    for index in range(len(seq)):
        place = seq[index]
        if place == val:
            return index
        else:
            return int("-1")

def init_nested_list(size_outer, size_inner):
    cal = []
    for outer_index in range(size_outer):
        nested_list = []
        for inner_index in range(size_inner):
            nested_list.append("-")
        cal.append(nested_list)
    return cal

def book_slot(cal,days_labels, times_labels, day, time):
    pos1 = find_index(day, days_labels)
    desired_day = cal[pos1]
    pos2 = find_index(time, times_labels)
    desired_time = desired_day[pos2]
    if desired_day == "X":
        print("We are sorry - that time is not available. Please try again.")
    else:
        print("Appointment is booked.")


days_labels = ["Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"]
times_labels = ["9","10","11"]
cal = init_nested_list(len(days_labels), len(times_labels))
print("before" , cal)
book_slot(cal, days_labels, times_labels, "Friday", "10")
print("after" , cal)
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
before [['-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-']]
Appointment is booked.
after [['-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-']]
```

This is the output I should be getting:

```
before [['-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-']]
Appointment is booked.
after [['-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-'], ['-', 'X', '-']]
We are sorry - that time is not available. Please try again.
```

As you can see, the correct output books the second element in the nested list(Friday at 10), but for my code it is not. I know desired_day is the day in cal that the user wants to book, but I'm just unsure of how to properly obtain that, and assign it to the string "X" when it is booked by the user. I also know that there is a coding error in the book_slot function that is causing this, but once again, I'm just unsure what it is...help please?

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in `book_slot` do you assign `X` to *anything*.  I should think you could use `pos1` and `pos2` to identify the slot to assign to.

Answer (score 0):

This will work. See the **Change #** notes in the code

```
def find_index(val, seq):
    return seq.index(val) #Change 1


def init_nested_list(size_outer, size_inner):
    cal = []
    for outer_index in range(size_outer):
        nested_list = []
        for inner_index in range(size_inner):
            nested_list.append("-")
        cal.append(nested_list)
    return cal


def book_slot(cal, days_labels, times_labels, day, time):
    pos1 = find_index(day, days_labels)
    desired_day = cal[pos1]
    pos2 = find_index(time, times_labels)
    if desired_day[pos2] is "X": # Change 2
        print("We are sorry - that time is not available. Please try again.")
    else:
        print("Appointment is booked.")
        desired_day[pos2] = "X" # Change 3


days_labels = ["Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"]
times_labels = ["9", "10", "11"]
cal = init_nested_list(len(days_labels), len(times_labels))
print("before", cal)
book_slot(cal, days_labels, times_labels, "Friday", "10")
book_slot(cal, days_labels, times_labels, "Friday", "10") # Change 4: Need to do a booking twice to make it fail :-)
print("after", cal)
```

will output:

```
('before', [['-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-']])
Appointment is booked.
('after', [['-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-'], ['-', 'X', '-']])
We are sorry - that time is not available. Please try again.
```